# ¿Cómo comparo filas utilizando ifelse?

Tags: r, condiciones, datarow

Tengo el siguiente dataframe, donde "RAM" correponde a la combinación única de las variables "Reb", "camp" y "mes". freq es la frecuencia de cada grupo "RAM"

```
df1 <- data.frame(camp = c("2006", "2006", "2009", "2009","2009", "2010", "2010","2010","2010","2011","2011","2011"),
              Reb = c("310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003","310020000003","310020000003","310020000003","310020000003"),
              mes = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "12","1","2","3","11","12"),
RAM = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10","11"),
freq = c("31", "68", "10", "30", "1", "34","40","9","15","3","62")
```

Tengo que hacer 2 cosas:

1) Reasignar aquellos "RAM" que tienen una frecuencia menor a 10 al RAM siguiente o anterior, siempre y cuando pertenezcan al mismo "camp". En este caso en concreto tendría que reasignar RAM 5 al RAM 4, ya que pertencen al mismo "camp" y el RAM 10 al 11. "ASÍ, ahora tanto RAM 4 y RAM 11 tendrían 2 posibles combinaciones distintas de Reb y mes". Hasta aquí el output sería:

```
df2 <- data.frame(camp = c("2006", "2006", "2009", "2009","2009", "2010", "2010","2010","2010","2011","2011","2011"),
              Reb = c("310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003", "310020000003","310020000003","310020000003","310020000003","310020000003"),
              mes = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "12","1","2","3","11","12"),
RAM = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "6","7","8","9","10","10"),
freq = c("31", "68", "10", "31","31,"34","40","9","15","65","65")
```

Para esto he pensado usar `ifelse`, poniendo como condición que si la fila 1 es igual a la 2, entonces RAM +1... pero no sé como usar nrow para integrarla en el `ifelse` y compara las filas. ¿Cómo lo hago? ¿Alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, imagino que `freq` es una variable numérica y no un `character` como en el ejemplo. Luego, se me ocurre una forma de resolverlo mediante `tidyverse`, como primer medida, tomando tu `df1`, lo ordenamos (por las dudas) y generamos un numerador o id por cada grupo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(camp, mes) %>% 
  group_by(camp) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() -> df1
```

Ahora, lo siguiente que vamos a hacer es trabajar con aquellas filas dónde `freq < 10` y vamos a calcular también la fila más cercana en dónde lo vamos a sumar:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(freq >= 10) %>% 
  left_join(df1 %>% 
              filter(freq < 10), 
              by="camp") %>% 
  filter(n.y == n.x-1 | n.y == n.x+1) %>% 
  group_by(camp) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(camp, n.x, freq.x, n.y, freq.y) -> casos

casos

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   camp [3]
  camp    n.x freq.x   n.y freq.y
  <fct> <int>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
1 2009      2     30     3      1
2 2010      2     34     3      9
3 2011      2     62     1      3
```

La salida es bastante clara, tenemos los datos de las filas que tenemos que eliminar `camp, n.y, freq.y` y a que filas las vamos a aplicar `camp, n.x, freq.x`, lo siguiente es hacer las dos cosas, sumar los menores de 10 y eliminar estas filas.

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(casos, by= c("camp", "n"="n.x")) %>% 
  mutate(freq = freq + ifelse(is.na(freq.y), 0, freq.y)) %>% 
  left_join(casos, by= c("camp", "n"="n.y")) %>%
  filter(is.na(n.x)) %>% 
  select(camp, Reb, mes, RAM, freq)

# A tibble: 8 x 5
  camp  Reb          mes   RAM    freq
  <fct> <fct>        <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 2006  310020000003 1     1        31
2 2006  310020000003 2     2        68
3 2009  310020000003 1     3        10
4 2009  310020000003 2     4        31
5 2010  310020000003 1     7        40
6 2010  310020000003 12    6        43
7 2010  310020000003 3     9        15
8 2011  310020000003 12    11       65
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio, como siempre muy claras y útiles tus respuestas

Comment: edité la pregunta porque me dí cuenta que necesito conservar todas las líneas. He intentado solventarlo modificando la última parte de la respuesta que me diste pero por un lado o por el otro, no consigo obtener lo que quiero.

Comment: Es decir, ¿quieres sumar pero no eliminar las filas?

Comment: Patricio puse una pregunta nueva que solventa mejor mi duda desde otro planteamiento que hice. ¿Cómo renumero categorías usando condicionales? Tu respuesta en este caso ha sido muy útil, agradecería que me ayudaras en lo nuevo que se me ha ocurrido.